# odoo inherit a model and "key error [my_database]"

Tags: odoo

I want to try to learn Odoo _inherit. But I have this error right now. And I couldn't solve the problem.

my module name is `stock.info` and I want the inherit `product.template` model.

but this error came.

```
TypeError: Many2many fields stock.info.taxes_id and product.template.taxes_id use the same table and columns
```

I added `product.template` to my depends in manifest too. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reminder for future questions: You should provide code for your Problem and not only an error message.

Like the error says you have 2 many2many fields which refers to the same table and columns.

You have to know that many2many fields in Odoo generate a mapping table in the database with two columns which are foreign keys to tables of the referenced models. The name of the mapping table and the column names are automatically generated by default. So if the automatic generation for your field creates the same name for table/columns which are already in use, you will get this error.

To solve this, you can assign additional attributes when defining your field.

So your field could like like this:

```
taxes_ids = fields.Many2many(relation='stock_info_account_tax_rel', column1='product_id', column2='tax_id')
```

(remember that many2many fields should be named with suffix `_ids` and not `_id`)

Take a look at the documentation for further informations: [odoo.fields.Many2many](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.Many2many)

> Parameters:
>
> comodel_name – name of the target model (string) mandatory
> except in the case of related or extended fields
>
> relation (str) – optional name of the table that stores the relation
> in the database
>
> column1 (str) – optional name of the column referring to “these”
> records in the table relation
>
> column2 (str) – optional name of the column referring to “those”
> records in the table relation
>
> The attributes relation, column1 and column2 are optional. If not
> given, names are automatically generated from model names, provided
> model_name and comodel_name are different!
>
> Note that having several fields with implicit relation parameters on a
> given model with the same comodel is not accepted by the ORM, since
> those field would use the same table. The ORM prevents two many2many
> fields to use the same relation parameters, except if
>
> both fields use the same model, comodel, and relation parameters are
> explicit; or
>
> at least one field belongs to a model with _auto = False.

Comment: In this case the parameter `relation` is the interesting one.